# iPhone - UIDatePicker leaks?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, datepicker

I have a UIDatePicker in interface builder which is connected to my outlet, and i release it in my dealloc method.

It leaks so much, when i load the view controller and it leaks even more as i scroll through it

- Leaked Object: NSDateComponents
- Responsible Frame: UIDatePickerView
- Number of leaks: about 30 (depends on
  how much i scroll through the picker)
- Total Leak Size: 4 kb (everytime i
  load the viewcontroller)

Anybody else has this problem with date pickers?

Comment: Post any code related to storing the selected date.

Comment: I don't store it, I don't even use it in any way, and it still leaks

Comment: you should still post your code

Answer (score 0):

Dó you provide an NSDate object to the picker, and I'd you do, is it properly released ?
Any object you provide to a foundation class should be released, the receiving class will send a retain message to the object.

Answer (score 0):

There was a leak in OS 5.x pertaining to scrolling cells into and out of view.  See this post:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061339/instruments-reports-libsystem-c-leak)