# instruments reports libsystem_c leak

Tags: ios, instruments, memory-leaks

I have a very strange, very repeatable leak that doesn't appear to have anything to do with the functions I have defined.  As you can see the responsible library is lybsystem_c.

Instruments reports a 48B leak when I scroll my grouped table view down below the screen (by dragging very fast).  It bounces back, and the red bar appears.

[image: instruments screen capture]

Has anyone experienced this issue?
Does anyone understand how I might be responsible for this?
Is there a way to prove this is a framework bug?  Or an Instruments bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a known bug in iOS 5.1 and is being discussed in the iOS Developer Forums as such. You can find the relevant thread by searching in the forums for "strdup". See the thread titled "Elements App Memory Leak". Search for the post from an Apple employee.

Reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762995/memory-leak-every-time-uiscrollview-is-released)